# How do you extract the raw image from a JPEG taken by the v2 camera?

Tags: camera, raspicam, image

I'm very new to working with the Raspberry Pi. For a project, I must have the raw images taken by the camera instead of the processed JPEGs. If I take a raw image using:

```
raspistill -r -o test.jpg
```

then how do I extract the raw image from test.jpg or process test.jpg to give me a readable raw file (.raw) back? I've seen many solutions online, but either they haven't worked for me or I don't know how to use them.

Comment: What methods did you use, and how did they fail?

Comment: The [raw bayer captures](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#raw-bayer-data-captures) recipe in the picamera docs goes through the basics (and should be sufficient for your case if you simply load `test.jpg` instead of capturing it). For more detail (dealing with rotation, camera modes etc.) see the [PiBayerArray](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera/blob/master/picamera/array.py#L332) source

Answer (score 2):

In Python you can use https://github.com/OsmoSystems/picamraw/ to extract the raw Bayer data or a rudimentary demosaiced RGB image. The result is a numpy array that you can use with a variety of other python tools. This basic example should display the raw image:

First, install matplotlib and picamraw with `pip install matplotlib picamraw`.

Then, import the code, grab the bayer array, convert it to RGB and display it:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import picamraw

raw_bayer = picamraw.PiRawBayer(
    filepath='path/to/image.jpeg',
    camera_version=picamraw.PiCameraVersion.V2,
)

plt.imshow(raw_bayer.to_rgb())
```

Full disclosure: my team just released that package. Let us know if you have any questions!

Comment: Current RPF images (using Raspbian Stretch) have the standard Python 3.5 installed. So people would have to kay their hands on a later version first. Probably need to compile it themselves. Not a great idea

Comment: great point! We're mainly using it for offboard processing, so we focused on 3.6. Leaving out python 3.5 was an oversight. I just added 3.5 support, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: Of course, in order to use matplotlib as in the example I provided, you'll have to have matplotlib set up with a functional backend. I haven't tested that onboard a pi.

Comment: I have actually played around with matplotlib on a Pi running Raspbian Stretch w Python 3.5, so I think that should be OK